# How do I fix a messed up IIS 6 install?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

Setup:
Windows Server 2003
IIS 6

The server dumps out the contents of the FrontPage Server Extensions DLL instead of doing anything useful whenever I do anything related to Server Extensions.

Are there any ways to fix this, short of completely reinstalling the operating system?

Just in case I wasn't clear, this is what I get in the browser:

> MZÿÿ¸@àº´ Í!¸LÍ!This program cannot be run in DOS mode. $o•DY+ô* +ô* +ô* +ô+ $ô* Ãë. (ô* Ãë .ô* Ûë! )ô* .Ö *ô* +ô* $ô* Rich+ô* PELNbéCà! 0a (and it goes on...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B894634) is an old KB article that describes a similar situation - perhaps the same fix will work for IIS6.

Answer (score 1):

If you're close to an OS reinstall, I'd definitely remove IIS, clear out \inetpub & \system32\inetsrv etc,  reboot, & reinstall first.  Just for kicks.

Also, this is a pretty solid [IIS6 troubleshooting page](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2005/12/31/HOWTO_Basics_of_IIS6_Troubleshooting.aspx) - because if you're like me, anything you manage to hose once, you'll hose again in a similar way.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wiping the OS is the most time effective solution in case you haven't spent much work setting up up until now - it should take about an hour and you won't have to attend it most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

For start Just:

control panel => add remove program => add/remove windows components

and nextnextnext throe it. Without changing anything! It does some (don't know what exactly) house keeping.